# properties of two positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$A,B∈ M_n (R)$ is a positive definite matrix.Then

a)$A^2$ is positive definite.

b)If A and B commutes then $A^k + B^k$ positive definite.

c)$AB + BA$ is positive definite.

d)If A and B commutes then $f(AB)$ is positive definite for any polynomial with positive coefficients.

a is true, for b) I can say that seperately they are positive definite but I am not getting what about their sum! c,d compltely clueless. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4):

You have to show two things:

1. If A, B are positiv definite then A+B is positiv definite
2. If A, B are positive and AB = BA, then AB (and also BA) is positive definite

1: 
It holds: $x^T(A+B)x = x^TAx + x^TBx > 0$ thus A+B is positiv definite.

Can you cantinue with 2 by yourself?

Comment: well, $(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2+ AB+BA$ so I am not sure whether $A^2+B^2$ will be positive definite or semidefinite.I guess semidefinite.

Comment: @miosaki you have already shown if A is positive definite then A^2 is positive definite. Similarly, B^2 is positive definite. Also, you know that if X and Y are positive definite, then X + Y is positive definite. If you put X as A^2 and Y as B^2, what do you get?

Comment: oopss okay okay okay...so $A^k+B^k$ is PD :)

Answer (score 3):

Supplementing Hans, c) is generally false without the additional assumption: Inspired by [the answer of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/product-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-is-positive-definite), you can take $A = \pmatrix{ 1 & 2\cr 2 & 5\cr}$, $B = \pmatrix{1 & -1\cr -1 & 2\cr}$ to obtain a counterexample, as
$$\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 } (AB+BA) \pmatrix{1\\0} = -2.$$