# Product of two positive compact, self adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

If we have two positive compact , self adjoint operators; $A$, $B$. Is the product $AB$ a positive operator?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Counterexample:
$$
A = \pmatrix{ 1 & 2\cr 2 & 5\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{1 & -1\cr -1 & 2\cr}\\ 
AB = \pmatrix{-1 & 3\cr -3 & 8\cr}\\ 
\left\langle AB\pmatrix{1\\0},\pmatrix{1\\0} \right\rangle =  \pmatrix{1&0} A B \pmatrix{1\cr 0\cr} = -1
$$
(example taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/product-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-is-positive-definite/113859#113859)).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that "positive" here means that the quadratic form is positive, right? In this case, I guess that the proposition is false unless $[A, B]=0$. You can find counterexamples even in finite dimensional spaces, so the compactness assumption does not help you much.

Comment: In the sense that A is positive iff $<Ax, x>= 0$ for all $x$ in our space

Answer (score 0):

The product of positive operators is not even selfadjoint in general. For instance, 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},
$$
while
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Note that since $A,B$ positive implies that they are selfadjoint, $AB$ positive implies that $AB=BA$. So the product of any two non-commutative positives will not be positve. In finite dimension this means that two positives commute if and only if they are simultaneously diagonalizable.