# $A\succeq B\succeq 0$ and $C\succeq 0$ imply $AC-BC\succeq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are positive semidefinite real matrices such that $A\succeq B$, do we have:
>   $$
> AC\succeq BC\quad\text{and}\quad CA\succeq CB.\tag{i}
> $$
>   Here, $A$, $B$, and $C$ share the same dimensions so that the multiplications above make sense.

Context: originally I had to prove $\text{tr}(AC)\geq\text{tr}(BC)$, which I have by using the Cholesky decomposition $C=LL'$:
$$
\text{tr}(AC)-\text{tr}(BC)=\text{tr}(ALL')-\text{tr}(BLL')=\text{tr}(L'AL)-\text{tr}(L'BL)=\text{tr}(L'(A-B)L)
$$
which is nonnegative because the matrix $L'(A-B)L$ is positive semidefinite. Then, I noted that my result will also follow if either equality in (i) holds, hence this question. Thank you very much.

Comment: what is your definition of the partial order?

Comment: @OfirSchnabel $X\succeq Y$ iff $X-Y$ is positive semidefinite. Thanks.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel Sorry for being obtuse, but isn't that just restating the problem?

Comment: Look in this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/product-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-is-positive-definite

Comment: And also here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19100/product-of-positive-matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Assume that $A$ and $C$ do not commute. Is $AC$ positive semidefinite?

The following is an example taken from [Is the product of symmetric positive semidefinite matrices positive definite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/product-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-is-positive-definite)

$$ A=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2\\ 2 & 5\end{array} \right)\quad \text{and}\quad
C=\left( \begin{array}{rr} 1 & -1\\ -1 & 2\end{array} \right) $$
are positive semidefinite. It is easy to check that $A\geq (3-2\sqrt{2})I$. On the other hand
$$ AC=\left( \begin{array}{rr} -1 & 3\\ -3 & 8\end{array} \right)$$ is not positive semidefinite as $\langle ACx,x\rangle=-1$ for $x^{T}=(1, 0)$. Thus the inequality
$$ AC \geq (3-2\sqrt{2})C$$
does not have sense.

Comment: Well, one could still consider $X\succeq 0$ if $X$ had real nonnegative eigenvalues. Alternatively, since the matrices involved are symmetric, $X\succeq 0$ could as well mean that $X$ is similar to a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix.

Comment: @janko I read the links given above by Ofir so I understand what you are saying. However, I think the hint is too brief. Can you write a more full answer? I'll gladly accept.