# Is this matrix positive definite (are eigenvalues always positive)?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, covariance

I am not a mathematician, could you please tell me whether,

$(\Sigma_A) * (\Sigma_B)^{-1} $ is positive-definite or not?

Where $\Sigma_A$ and $\Sigma_B$ are covariance matrices of A and B. 
And, "A" and "B" are two real general matrices with dimensions [mxn].

I am programming something and it is important to know whether the eigenvalues of the above multiplications are always positive or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Sigma_A \Sigma_B^{-1}$ will not always be positive definite, since it will not generally be symmetric.  However, it **will** have positive eigenvalues, and these eigenvalues are the same as those of the matrix $\Sigma_B^{-1/2}\Sigma_A\Sigma_B^{-1/2}$, which is positive definite.

Comment: Sometimes one talks about unsymmetric positive definite systems, tho (e.g. [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(79)90122-8)).

Comment: @J.M. sure, but covariance matrix are specifically of the form $\Sigma_A = AA^T$ (or sometimes $A^TA$).

Comment: I'm well aware, so the product is certainly not SPD. Just saying that "positive definite" doesn't always include "symmetric" as a condition.

Comment: @J.M. Ah, I see now.  If I remember correctly, there exists an example of symmetric positive definite matrices $A,B$ such that the product $AB$ fails to be (unsymmetric) positive definite.

Comment: @J.M. see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/is-the-product-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-positive-definite/113859#113859) in particular

Comment: Just found that answer too. :)