# Is the product of matrices compatible with the signature?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$, $B$ square matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ with the same dimension. If $A$ is positive definite and $B$ is positive semidefinite, is $AB$ positive semidefinite?
If yes, prove it. If no, counterexample it.

What if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric?

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is well stated. Definition of positive (semi)definite matrix assumes symmetry, but the product of two symmetric matrices need not be symmetric.

Comment: Positive definite = eigenvalues are $>0$. Positive semidefinite = eigenvalues are $\ge 0$. No symmetry required.

Comment: @user459312 That is **not** what positive definite usually means, although there is a definition that allows for non-symmetric positive definite matrices.

Comment: @Przemek in some areas, a real matrix $A$ is called positive definite if and only if $A + A^T$ is positive definite (in the usual sense).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom in every area I encountered it, *that* was the definition. But no matter, I got the counterexample I wanted.

Comment: @user459312 right.  Note that this is **not** the same as saying that the eigenvalues are positive.  It is, however, an established fact that positive definite matrices have eigenvalues with positive real part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrices should be symmetric by definition of positive definiteness.

If $A$ and $B$ commute, the result is positive semidefinite again. For the case in which they don't commute, there is a [counterexpample](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113859/455617).

Proof for the case $AB = BA$: Since $A>0$, there exists a unique symmetric matrix $A^{1/2}>0$ such that $A^{1/2}A^{1/2} = A$. We can write

$$\langle AB x,x\rangle = \langle BA x,x\rangle = \langle A^{-1/2}A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}A^{1/2}x,x\rangle = \langle A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}x,x\rangle = \langle B(A^{1/2}x), A^{1/2}x\rangle =\langle Bz,z\rangle \ge 0,$$
with $z = A^{1/2}x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In particular I appreciated the counterexample on the above link.