# Product of 2 positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

I got a problem I can't solve for in linear algebra.
My task is to find if the product of 2 positive definite matrices is also positive definite?
My intuition tells me it is not true but I cannot find a counterexample.

If my intuition was false, do this 2 matrices need to be symmetric to be true?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: Use the property that a matrix is positive definite iff it's eigenvalues are positive. A positive definite matrix is symmetric by definition.

Comment: @Jules: Thats not correct. A positive definite matrix does not necessarily has to be symmetric. E.g. consider the $2\times 2$ matrix with ones on the diagonal and a one on the $12$ position as well. It is clearly positive definite but certainly not symmetric

Comment: That's why I said that positive definite matrices are symmetric by definition. Perhaps some authors have a different definition, but this is the most common one.

Comment: Otherwise, consider (0 1, -1 0)^2.

Comment: Although, if we require symmetry in the definition then it is still false because the product of two symmetric matrices is not necessarily symmetric.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the product of symmetric positive semidefinite matrices positive definite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/is-the-product-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-positive-definite)

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer on another forum finally. 
For me, a matrix is positive definite if xT*A*x>0 for all column vector x.

We have A=[1,2;2,5] and B=[1,-1;-1,2] 2 positive definite matrix

AB=[-1,3;-3,8] is not positive definite as [1,0]AB[1;0]=-1

The issue with eigenvalue and positive definite matrix is that there are not equivalent
-> If the matrix is positive definite then its eigenvalue are positive.
But positive eigenvalues does not guarantee that the matrix is positive definite.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

We can define a (not necessarily symmetric) real $n \times n$ matrix $A$ to be positive definite if ${\bf x}^T A {\bf x} \geq 0$ for all ${\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and equality holds if and only if $x={\bf 0}$.

Then
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1& 2a\\
0& 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
is positive definite if and only if $|a|<1$.  And so is the transpose.  But, if you try to compute the product of some of these matrices, you'll find a product to two which is no longer definite.

Here's a non-symmetric positive definite matrix which squares to a indefinite matrix:
$$L = \begin{pmatrix}
1& 1\\
-1& 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

For symmetric positive definite matrices, as Jules says in the comments above, the product of two symmetric matrices need not be symmetric.  Indeed, if $A$, $B$, and $AB$ are symmetric, then we must have that $AB = (AB)^T = B^T A^T = BA$.  However, since every matrix commutes with itself, the square of a positive definite matrix is positive definite.

[This](http://web.mit.edu/14.102/www/notes/posdef.pdf) note may be helpful regarding whether or not to insist that the matrix be defined as a symmetric matrix.  The example below is inspired by this note.

A search of "non symmetric positive definite matrix" will yield this and many other discussions including some here on math.stackexchange.

One final example: consider $q(x,y) = {\bf x}^T A {\bf x} = x^2 + 2axy + y^2$. We find that the symmetric matrix associated to this quadratic form is

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
1& a\\
a& 1
\end{pmatrix},$$
so that $q(x,y) = {\bf x}^T M {\bf x}$.  This is positive definite if and only if its determinant is positive (which proves the claim about the matrix $A$ above).