# Definiteness of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am studying definiteness of matrices. Like positive, negative and indefinite matrices. I am confused whether this concept of definiteness is only for symmetric matrices or we do it for any matrix ? 
Further how this idea is related to quadratic form?

Answer (score 2):

Most authors restrict the terms "positive definite" etc. to hermitian matrices (symmetric in the real case), but some
 do not.   See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Extension_for_non-symmetric_matrices).

Comment: For hermitian matrices we can decide their definiteness using sign of eigenvalues but what about a matrix which is not hermitian ?

Comment: Positive definiteness of a non-hermitian matrix $A$ (for those who allow it) is equivalent to positive definiteness of the hermitian matrix $A+A^*$.

Comment: How can we prove or disprove this positiveness of A and B doesn't imply that of AB?

Comment: @PrakashNainwal: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/is-the-product-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-positive-definite