# Is the resultant will be positive definite of not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

I have two square matrices $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&0&0\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&0&0\\
0&0&a_{33}&a_{34}\\
0&0&a_{43}&a_{44}
\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11}&0&0&0\\
0&b_{22}&0&0\\
0&0&b_{33}&0\\
0&0&0&b_{44}
\end{bmatrix},$which are in product form as shown in the following equation
\begin{equation}
A^{-1}BA
\end{equation}
where $B$ is a diagonal positive definite matrix. $A$ can be positive, negative or indefinite matrix.

If the main diagonal elements $B$ are equal (i.e., B is scalar positive definite), then obviously $A^{-1}BA=BI,$ which is a positive definite. But I am not sure what will be the result if $B$ is a diagonal with different elements on its main diagonal?

Comment: There is no reason to believe that $A^{-1}BA$ is symmetric, let alone positive definite. In fact, $A^{-1}BA$ is symmetric if and only if $A^2$ commutes with $B$. If the diagonal entries of $B$ are distinct, then $A^{-1}BA$ is symmetric if and only if $A^2$ is diagonal.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I am wondering why is the result of $A^{-1}BA$  needs to be symmetric? I was asking about positive definiteness of the resultant, and asymmetric matrix can be positive definite. For example \begin{bmatrix}
5&1\\
2& 3
\end{bmatrix}, is asymmetric but positive definite

Comment: There are two common definitions for positive definite. One definition requires that the matrix is symmetric, the other does not. Because the matrices you started with are both symmetric, I assumed you were using the first definition.

Comment: With that said, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113842/81360) seems relevant

Comment: For my case $A$ is asymmetric. I got an idean, help me if am wrong. The product of two matrices 
(1) PD$\times$PD=PD 
(2) ND$\times$PD=ND
(3) ND$\times$ND=PD
where PD and ND represent Positive and Negative definite matrices respectively. 
if A is PD, then $A^{-1}$ is also PD, and the resultant will be like PD*PD*PD=PD
if A is ND then $A^{-1}$ is also $ND$, and the resultant will be like ND*PD*ND=PD

Comment: As the post I linked demonstrates, it is not true that $PD \times PD = PD$.

Answer (score 1):

**Counterexample:** Take
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&1&0&0\\1&2&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1}, \quad 
B = \pmatrix{10\\&1\\&&1\\&&&1}.
$$
We find that
$$
A^{-1}BA = \pmatrix{13&6&0&0\\-6&-2&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1}
$$
has a negative diagonal entry and therefore cannot be positive definite.

Comment: I think the signs of the elements on diagonal has decides negative of positive definiteness of a matrix IFF the matrix is Diagonal matrix. In the counter example you provided the resultant is positive definite. I checked on MATLAB

Comment: @NihadAli What exactly is your definition of positive definite? Typically, we say that $M$ is positive definite if and only if for every non-zero column-vector $x$, $x^TMx > 0$. However, with $M = A^{-1}BA$ as above, taking `x = [0;1;0;0]` yields $x^TMx = -2 < 0$

Comment: @NihadAli Note that for a non-symmetric matrix $M$, it is no longer true that $M$ is positive deifnite if and only if its eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: I check definiteness of a matrix based on eigen values.. 

If all eigen values are positive then matrix is positive.... 

If all negative then negative..

Comment: @NihadAli That is not correct. I strongly recommend that you review your notes for the definition of "positive definite".

Comment: Yeah you were right, eigen values procedure is valid for symmetric matrices and may not necessarily valid for non-symmetric matrices. I am really thankful for your precious time. Thanks alot.

Comment: @NihadAli Glad to help