# Range of a product of traces

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

What is the range of $A = tr(q[r, h]) tr(p[r,h])$ where $[m,n]=mn-nm$ is the commutator of $m$ and $n$,

knowing that

- all matrices are hermitian $d \times d$.
- $ q,p,r $ are trace one, PSD and idempotent, hence the range of $tr(qr)$ and $tr(pr)$ is in $[0,1]$;
- h is involutionary, hence its trace is in $[-d,d]$.

I have trouble determining bounds given that $h$ is not PSD and I am unsure whether $qr$ or $pr$ are PSD again.

Comment: What do you mean by $q[r,h]$ ? Is it the product of $q$ by $[r,h]$ , the commutator $rh-hr$ ?

Comment: yes its the product of $q$ with the commutator. My trouble boils down to bound $tr(qrh)$ as $h$ is not PSD.

Comment: and it is also not clear whether the product $qp$ will be also PSD as PSD matrices do not from a complex vector space.

Comment: I have attempted to improve your question. Do you agree ?

Comment: When you say "whether the product is PSD **again**", do you mean that $q$ and $p$ are PSD ?

Comment: Yes $p,q $ are PSD I added that, but I don't know if $ pq$ is PSD. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: See here for your last sentence : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113842/305862

Comment: @JeanMarie the link seems to refer to real symmetric matrices and not to complex hermitian matrices. I don't know how to translate the proof for the latter case.

Comment: $p$ and $q$ might not commute, so their product is not PSD in general I guess. Then I don't know any bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably $d\ge2$. Let $k=rh-hr$. For any unit vectors $u\in\operatorname{range}(r)$ and $v\in\ker(r)=\operatorname{range}(r)^\perp$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
ku&=(rh-hr)u=rhu-hu=(r-1)hu,\\
kv&=(rh-hr)v=rhv.\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore $\|ku\|_2,\|kv\|_2\le1$ and $ku\perp kv$. It follows that $\|ik\|_2\le1$. Moreover, since $ik$ is Hermitian, $\operatorname{tr}\big(q(ik)\big)$ and $\operatorname{tr}\big(p(ik)\big)$ are real numbers whose absolute values are at most $1$. Hence
$$
\operatorname{tr}(q[r,h])\operatorname{tr}(p[r,h])
=-\operatorname{tr}\big(q(ik)\big)\operatorname{tr}\big(p(ik)\big)\in[-1,1].\tag{$\ast$}
$$
E.g. when
$$
q=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{i}{2}\\ \frac{i}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\ &&0_{(d-2)\times(d-2)}},
\quad r=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0\\ &&0_{(d-2)\times(d-2)}},
\quad h=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0\\ &&I_{d-2}},
$$
the lower bound $-1$ in $(\ast)$ is attained by $p=q$ and the upper bound $1$ is attained by $p=q^\top$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you explain why $tr(pik)$ is in **absolute** value less than 1?

Comment: @user18722294 Write $p=uu^\ast$ for some unit vector $u$. Then $|\operatorname{tr}(p(ik))|=|\operatorname{tr}(uu^\ast(ik))|=|u^\ast(ik)u|\le\|ik\|_2=1$.

Comment: thanks, does the same hold for the lower bound -1?

Comment: @user18722294 Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$