# Product of matrices associated to bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a real vector space of finite dimension where
$f,g: V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ are two symmetric positive semidefinite bilinear forms. For a given basis $B$ of $V$, there are two symmetric positive semidefinite matrices $F$ and $G$ that represent $f$ and $g$, respectively. The matrix product $H=FG$ represents a positive semidefinite bilinear form $h$ on $V$.

I think the definition of $h$ does not depend on the basis $B$ and therefore neither on the associated matrices. How do I define the operation $(f,g)\mapsto h$ without making reference to associated matrices?

Comment: *"The matrix product = represents a positive semidefinite bilinear form ℎ on "*...  consider multiplying the following two symmetric PD matrices $F=\left[\begin{matrix}13 & 43\\43 & 145\end{matrix}\right],G=\left[\begin{matrix}117 & 87\\87 & 74\end{matrix}\right]$ -- the product is an indefinite matrix, contradicting your statement

Comment: Perhaps you would be interested in the matrix $H=F M^{-1} G$, where $M$ is the mass matrix. That is, the matrix with entries $M_{ij} = (b_i, b_j)$ where $b_i$ are the basis vectors in $B$.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply a basis transformation to both factors, so that $x=Su$ and $y=Tv$, the matrix of the bilinear form $x^\top Fy=u^\top S^\top FTv=u^\top(S^\top FT)v$ becomes $S^\top FT$, and the matrix of the bilinear form $x^\top Gy=u^\top S^\top GTv=u^\top(S^\top GT)v$ becomes $S^\top GT$. Multiplying these two new matrices yields $S^\top FTS^\top GT$. Now $h$ would be defined as $u^\top(S^\top FTS^\top GT)v=(u^\top S^\top)(FTS^\top G)(Tv)$ $=x^\top(FTS^\top G)y$, which will generally not be equal to $x^\top FGy$, the value defined for the original bases.

The reason this doesn’t work is that multiplying matrices of bilinear forms isn’t a natural thing to do – you typically multiply matrices when they represent linear operations that you can compose, but the matrix that represents a bilinear form doesn’t represent a linear operation.

Comment: A small note; The matrices $F$ and $G$ do represent the linear operations of currying (partial application of the bilinear forms to only one vector). But that maps $V$ to it’s dual, $V’$, so you can’t compose them. For the operation to make sense you would need to put an inverse mass matrix between $F$ and $G$ to convert the dual vector output of $F$ into its Riesz representation in $V$, which can then be input into $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g$ is definite and $B$ is a $g$-orthonormal basis. Then $G$ is the identity and $H = F$ implying that $h = f$. But clearly there are $f, g, B$ such that $h \ne f$.

Consider the simple case of one real dimension with $f(x,y) = 2xy$ and $g(x,y) = 5xy$. Then $g$ has orthonormal basis $1/\sqrt 5$ and $h(x,y) = f(x,y) = 2xy$ in this basis. But now choose $3$ as a basis; then
$$
  h(3,3) = f(3,3)g(3,3) = 9\cdot 90 \implies h(1,1) = 90 \implies h(x,y) = 90xy.
$$
Thus $h$ is highly basis dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if $F,G$ are real symmetric positive semidefinite matrices, then $F^{\frac{1}{2}}GF^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is also symmetric positive semidefinite.

Consider the example by @user8675309, in which

$$
F = \begin{pmatrix}
13 & 43 \\
43 & 145
\end{pmatrix} \qquad
G = \begin{pmatrix}
117 & 87 \\
87 & 145
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then
$$
F^{\frac{1}{2}} = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{170}}
\begin{pmatrix}
19 & 43 \\
43 & 151
\end{pmatrix} \qquad
G^{\frac{1}{2}} = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{257}}
\begin{pmatrix}
150 & 87 \\
87 & 74
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
F^{\frac{1}{2}}GF^{\frac{1}{2}} = 
\frac{1}{17}
\begin{pmatrix}
45250 & 144754 \\
144754 & 465226
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The eigenvalues of $F^{\frac{1}{2}}GF^{\frac{1}{2}}$ are $\lambda_1 = 2(7507 - \sqrt{56270485})$ and $\lambda_2 = 2(7507 + \sqrt{56270485})$, which are both positive.

I found stated in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/is-the-product-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-positive-definite) thread that $FG$ and $F^{\frac{1}{2}}GF^{\frac{1}{2}}$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues, and this example confirms it.

Let $P$ be an orthogonal matrix (a change from one orthogonal basis to another). Then $(P^{\top}F^{\frac{1}{2}}P)(P^{\top}GP)(P^{\top}F^{\frac{1}{2}}P) = P^{\top}(F^{\frac{1}{2}}GF^{\frac{1}{2}})P$. In other words the operation $(f, g) \mapsto h$ given by the following steps:

1. pick an orthogonal basis $B$ of $V$;
2. represent $f$ as a matrix $F$ w.r.t. $B$;
3. represent $g$ as a matrix $G$ w.r.t. $B$;
4. compute $H = F^{\frac{1}{2}}GF^{\frac{1}{2}}$;
5. lef $h$ be the bilinear form associated to $H$ w.r.t. $B$.

is well-defined because it does not depend on the basis $B$. This is really the operation I cared about. Is it possible to define it without using the isomorphism between forms and matrices?

Comment: You should probably open a new question with this information and follow up question.

Comment: I'm also not really convinced, either that it's basis independent or that it's what you want. Apply the same argument as I did in my answer: assume $g$ is positive definite and choose $B$ to be $g$-orthonormal. Then again $G = 1$ and $H = F$. So either (1) this construction is really basis independent and we just have $h = f$ so it's uninteresting; or (2) it is not basis independent.