# What's relationship between ST and TS's eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

this comes from a comment of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113842/is-the-product-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-positive-definite)

If 
and 
are ×
and ×
matrices, 
and 
have the same nonzero eigenvalues: 
is an eigenvector of 
iff 
is an eigenvector of 
, with the same nonzero eigenvalue.

I try to proof this

if 
is an eigenvector of  => 
is an eigenvector of

$\begin{align}
STu &= \lambda u \tag{1}
\end{align}$

left multiply by T, then
$\begin{align}
TSTu &= \lambda Tu \tag{2}
\end{align}$

but I'm blocked (2)=>(1)
if $TSTu=\lambda Tu$, I can't multiply left with $T^-1$ since
T is not square matrix, even T is square matrix, it still may
not be invertible.

and also why OP in that thread says `have the same nonzero eigenvalues`,
from (1)=>(2) it seemed the zero eigenvalues are also corresponding?

Comment: Matrices make non comitative group so.       CA - CB = C( A-B ). You'll need consider T as entirely zero matrix and wanted idea

Comment: If $Tu=0$ then (1) gives $u=0$ (as long as $\lambda \neq 0$). So $Tu \neq 0$ and it is an eigen vector of $TS$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda \ne 0$ is needed to show that $Tu \ne 0$ (remember, an eigenvector is a **nonzero** vector such that ...).

It's **not** true that if $Tu$ is an eigenvector of $TS$ then $u$ is an eigenvector of $ST$.  For example, consider
$$ S = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0\cr 
                1 & 1 & 0\cr},\ T = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr},\
ST = \pmatrix{2 & 2\cr 2 & 2\cr},\ TS = \pmatrix{2 & 2 & 0\cr 2 & 2 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$$

Try $u= \pmatrix{1\cr 0\cr}$.  Then $Tu = \pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr 0\cr}$ is an eigenvector of $TS$ for eigenvalue $4$, but $u$ is not an eigenvector of $ST$.

Comment: If S and T are both square, would  is an eigenvector of  iff  is an eigenvector of  holds? I can only prove when T is invertible, just left multiply by $T^{-1} to (2) and get (1), but blocked when T is not invertible

Comment: If $T$ is a square matrix and not invertible, it has a nontrivial null space.  Take any $w \ne 0$ for which $Tw = 0$ and $u$ an eigenvector of $ST$ for $\lambda \ne 0$.  Then  $T(u+w) = Tu$ is an eigenvector of $TS$, but $u+w$ is not an eigenvector of $ST$.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument works. If $\lambda\ne0$ and $STu=\lambda u$ for nonzero $u$, then $Tu\ne0$ and $TS(Tu)=\lambda Tu$. This shows that any nonzero eigenvalue of $ST$ is an eigenvalue of $TS$. As the roles can be exchanged, you get that $ST$ and $TS$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues.

The same idea shows that the geometric multiplicity is preserved for nonzero $\lambda$. Indeed, if $STu=\lambda u$ and $STv=\lambda v$ for linearly independent $u,v$, if $aTu+bTv=0$ then
$$
au+bv=\frac1\lambda\,(aSTu+bSTv)=\frac1\lambda\,S (aTu+bTv)=0
$$
and so $a=b=0$. As for the algebraic multiplicity, the same ideas allow you to show that the generalized eigenspaces have the same dimension, so the algebraic multiplicity also agrees for nonzero $\lambda$. For an example of this, if $(ST-\lambda I)^2u=0$, then $$STSTu-2\lambda STu+\lambda^2u=0.$$ You cannot have $Tu=0$ for you would have $u=0$. Multiplying by $T$ on the left as before, $(TS-\lambda I)^2Tu=0$, and also as above one can show that the dimensions of the generalized eigenspaces agree.

When $\lambda=0$ the above argument fails because you may have $Tu=0$. But if $S,T$ are square then if $0$ is an eigenvalue of $ST$ it means that $ST$ is not invertible; this forces at least one of $S,T$ to be not invertible (use set) and so $TS$ cannot be invertible and $0$ is an eigenvalue of $TS$.

Things are slightly different if we allow non-square matrices. Take
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad T=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $$ST=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ with eigenvalues $0,2$ while $TS=2$ with eigenvalue $2$.

Comment: From your first paragraph, for the same $\lambda$, is multiplicity same? 
$STu_1 = \lambda u_1 $ & $STu_2 = \lambda u_2$ =>$TSTu_1 = \lambda T u_1 $ & $TSTu_2 = \lambda Tu_2$ (\*),the geometric multiplicity may collapse, since $Tu_1$ and $Tu_2$ can become linear dependent vector, but what happen to algebraic multiplicity, do they stay the same? I can't proof it since (\*) still doesn't mean $\lambda$ appeared twice as root in characteristic polynominal of TS.

Comment: Also a natural conclusion is if n>m, then ST must have (n-m) more  (with algebraic multiplicity)  0 eigenvalues than TS,right? since ST has n eigenvalues, and TS has m eigenvalues and they must correspond, then the leftover  (n-m) must be 0

Comment: The algebraic and geometric multiplicities are the same, I have edited the answer. Your conclusion about the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is correct.

Comment: say n>m, if excluding extra (n-m) 0 eigenvalues, based on your result, (since the nonzero algebraic multiplicity is same, say they occupy total r algebraic multiplicity),the left over 0 eigenvalues' algebraic multiplicity (which is m-r) must be same, but does the left over 0's eigenvalues' geometric multiplicity preserved or not?

Comment: No, it's not preserved. $$S=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad T= \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then $$ST= \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad TS=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ So $0$ has geometric multiplicity $1$ in $ST$ and $2$ in $TS$.